# for loop within d3.json

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, d3.js

d3.json was working fine till I included this for loop in it. I am populating the patientList object which is basically a list of patient names, where each patient would have an array of appointment dates and alpha beta values. The database stores multiple rows for each patient where the name and alpha beta values remain same but dates vary. Therefore, this for loop is to sort out the info with name as primary key.But I have no idea what's wrong in here as it's my first time working with d3 and js.

```
var data;
var patientList = {};

d3.json("data.php", function(error, json)  {
       if (error) return console.warn(error);
    data = json;

       for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)  {
        var name = data[i].name;

        if(!patientList[name])  {

        var newPatient = {
            dates: data[i].date,
            alpha: data[i].alpha,
            beta; data[i].beta
        };

        patientList[name] = newPatient;

        } else  {

        patientList[name].dates.push(data[i].date);
        }
    }
    alert("Hello," + data[3].name);
});
```

Any suggestions ??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what happens when you have the loop in there?

Comment: It doesn't pop up the second alert window with the for loop, otherwise it was doing so.

Comment: Are you retuning different JSON from the PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's just the typo in

```
beta; data[i].beta
```

which should be

```
beta: data[i].beta
```

What does the console.log say?

Comment: Changing that didn't fix the error, it doesn't pop up the second alert window. How do I check the console.log?? (I am a complete beginner with all this)

Comment: Error console comes up with- TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'patientList[name].dates.push')

Comment: I'm a beginner, too, so this might be wrong, but to me it seems you try to push a new value (data[i].date) into a value (patientList[name].dates) and not into an array like it's supposed to. Try to substitute the line where you define the dates (dates: data[i].date) with (dates: [data[i].date]).
And since you can see console.log now, do yourself a favor and change the "alert" to "console.log" if you just need it for debugging reasons.